# How to add dropdown menu to QMessageBox?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

After looking at some code I found on stackoverflow, I was able to find a way to add a table to a QmessageBox. Now that I have done that, I would like to place a drop down menu in the top right of the QmessageBox and I cannot figure out a way to do that (if it even is possible).

Here is my edited code:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.Qt import *
import sys


class MyMessageBox(QMessageBox):
    def __init__(self):
        QMessageBox.__init__(self)
        self.setSizeGripEnabled (True)

        self.setWindowTitle('Get Parent Script')
        self.setIcon(self.Question)
        #self.setText("Hello MessageBox")
        self.addButton("Select", QMessageBox.ActionRole)
        self.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Cancel)
        #self.addWidget(QInputDialog())

        self.addTableWidget (self)

        currentClick = self.exec_()


    def addTableWidget (self, parentItem) :
        self.l =  QVBoxLayout()
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(parentItem)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName ('tableWidget')

        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QString("Nuke Script;File Modification Time;User").split(";"))

        header = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader()
        header.setResizeMode(0, QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        header.setResizeMode(1, QHeaderView.Stretch)
        header.setResizeMode(2, QHeaderView.Stretch)
        stringlist = {u'/SEQ/ZZ/ZZ_012_001/Comp/nuke/scripts/comp':u'user1', u'/SEQ/ZZ/ZZ_012_001/Comp/nuke/scripts/comp/hello': u'user2'}
        row = 0
        for key, value in stringlist.iteritems():
            print key, value

            nameitem = QTableWidgetItem(str(key))
            codeitem = QTableWidgetItem(str(value))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row,0,nameitem)
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row,1,codeitem)
            row +=1

        self.tableWidget.resize(1000, 170)

        self.l.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.setLayout(self.l)

    def event(self, e):
        result = QMessageBox.event(self, e)
        self.setMinimumWidth(0)
        self.setMaximumWidth(16777215)
        self.setMinimumHeight(0)
        self.setMaximumHeight(16777215)
        self.setSizePolicy(
            QSizePolicy.Expanding,
            QSizePolicy.Expanding
        )
        self.resize(1000, 300)

        return result


def run_cli():
    #app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MyMessageBox()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_cli()
```

Comment: You could explain yourself better, when I run your code I see a QMessageBox that already has a QComboBox, after pressing the "OK" or "Cancel" button another window opens with a QTableWidget. What I do not understand in Where do you want to place the QComboBox? Do you want there to be only one window or two? Or do you want the QComboBox of the first window to be in the second window and so there is only one window?

Comment: Yikes! Weird it shows up in one window for me. Well anyways, what I am trying to do is have one window that has a table of data at the center as well as a drop down box in the top right. This drop down menu will generate the data in the table based on what the user selected.

Comment: You say in the top-right this the QComboBox, what should be shown in the top-left? Why is it necessary to use QMessageBox? In the following link I show the 2 windows that I get (only one at a time) https://imgur.com/a/0Vpfm99

Comment: Ah shoot sorry- I updated my code to remove a function call that I was trying out. I was initially trying to add a QInputDialogBox into the QMessageBox but that didnt work as it just creates two separate windows. I plan on just putting informative text in the top left of the window.

Comment: Okay, that answers my first question: *what should be shown in the top-left?*,  But you have not answered my second question: **Why is it necessary to use QMessageBox?**

Comment: Sorry! Text should be displayed in the top left. It is not necessary to use QMessageBox, it was just existing code. I am currently trying to figure out an alternative way to construct this window but I dont know where to start as I am  fairly new to pyqt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it is not optimal to use QMessageBox since I involve unnecessary work because this widget already has a predefined layout, instead you can create a widget based on a QDialog:

```py
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class Dialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)

        label = QtGui.QLabel("Text")
        combo = QtGui.QComboBox()
        combo.addItems(["option1", "option2", "option3"])

        self.tableWidget = QtGui.QTableWidget(2, 3)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(
            QtCore.QString("Nuke Script;File Modification Time;User").split(";")
        )

        header = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader()
        header.setResizeMode(0, QtGui.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        header.setResizeMode(1, QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        header.setResizeMode(2, QtGui.QHeaderView.Stretch)

        stringlist = {
            u"/SEQ/ZZ/ZZ_012_001/Comp/nuke/scripts/comp": u"user1",
            u"/SEQ/ZZ/ZZ_012_001/Comp/nuke/scripts/comp/hello": u"user2",
        }

        for row, (key, value) in enumerate(stringlist.iteritems()):
            nameitem = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(key))
            codeitem = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(value))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 0, nameitem)
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, codeitem)

        box = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(
            QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel,
            centerButtons=True,
        )
        box.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        box.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        lay = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(label, 0, 0)
        lay.addWidget(combo, 0, 1)
        lay.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        lay.addWidget(box, 2, 0, 1, 2)

        self.resize(640, 240)


def run_cli():
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Dialog()
    w.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_cli()
```

[image]

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you so much for all the help! That's exactly what I was looking for. So in general, is it better to construct custom windows using QDialog?

Comment: @lennyfoulds No, there are many options: QWidget, QDialog, QMainWindow, etc. The choice depends on the use, and how much personalization you want to make.